# An XPage Computed multi-value column will not behave as categorized as it does in the Notes Client

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, calculated-columns

I have a simple formula in my notes view categorized multi-value column (column 2) which pulls values from several other text fields and makes a string list out them:

> @Unique( @Trim( ProjTesters :  projDITTesters : projTechLead :
>   projDevelopers : projBA : projPM ))

When I view the result in the Notes Client, the column displays categorized properly.   However, in the Xpage View Container, it appears to be flat.

Also, I mention here that column 1 is a Total column whose value is 1 with Hide Detail Rows checked.

[Qty in Column 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3u8Yp.png)

Is there a way to do make the computed category render as a category in the browser?   Hasn't anyone else run into this problem?

Comment: Please copy the source code for your viewPanel into this question.  The problem is the way a column is defined in the NoteView does not automatically transfer to the viewPanel .. ie you need to define it to show as a categorized column in the viewPanel as well.

Comment: Hi Paul, long time no see.  
Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.  I ended up re-creating the view panel from scratch, and "somehow" that fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When You specify the "value" attribute for a viewPanel column that is categorized, You also have to specify the "columnName" property. Otherwise it will not know that column is a category.